# Not able to add foreign key constraint to pivot table

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-migrations

I am trying to create a pivot table, with foreign keys, this is the migration I have made in Laravel:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('player_position', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('player_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('position_id')->unsigned()->index();

        $table->foreign('player_id')->references('id')->on('players')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('position_id')->references('id')->on('positions')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

But, I get an error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: alter table `player_position` add constraint
>   `player_position_posi     tion_id_foreign` foreign key (`position_id`)
>   references `positions` (`id`) on delete cascade)
>
> ```
>                                                                          [PDOException]
> ```
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

I have read that usually foreign key constraint errors are about not assigning unsigned to fields, or already having records in the DB, but my DB is empty, and I my fields have unsigned, so don't know what is the problem?

Comment: I recommend you to not using constraints on your db. instead, try to manage it in your code.

Comment: @MortezaRajabi and why is it so ?

Comment: Managing such a table with constraints is hard, and you will have those errors every time you wanna add or delete something.

Comment: That's not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

For a field to be defined as a `foreign key`, the referenced parent field must have an `index` defined on it. And the datatype of both the column and its size must be the same.

I think you are violating some of the above rule.

Comment: But, they do have index defined on them

Comment: And what about the `datatype`?

Comment: As well, they are both integers

Comment: are they both the same type and length of integer though?. So both unsigned and both 11 chars long for example.

Comment: I had this issue.  Changing the parent id columns from `$table->bigIncrements` to `$table->increments` (to match `$table->integer` on the pivot table) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **->index()** method as it creates basic index while you want to add foreign key constraint which references primary key on another table.

```
 $table->integer('player_id')->unsigned();
 $table->integer('position_id')->unsigned();

 $table->foreign('player_id')->references('id')->on('players')->onDelete('cascade');
 $table->foreign('position_id')->references('id')->on('positions')->onDelete('cascade');
```